# Solving a system of three complex equations

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

Consider the following quantities:

```
    matA = {{y + Re[2 x2 x6 - x7], 
    x6 Re[x1], -(x5/2) - Im[2 x2 x6 - x7], -x6 Im[x1], 0, x6 Re[x1], 
    0, x6 Im[x1]}, {x6 Re[x1], y - x8, -x6 Im[x1], -(x4/2), x6 Re[x1],
     0, x6 Im[x1], 0}, {x5/2 + Im[2 x2 x6 - x7], x6 Im[x1], 
    y + Re[2 x2 x6 - x7], x6 Re[x1], 0, x6 Im[x1], 
    0, -x6 Re[x1]}, {x6 Im[x1], x4/2, x6 Re[x1], y - x8, x6 Im[x1], 
    0, -x6 Re[x1], 0}, {0, -x6 Re[x1], 0, -x6 Im[x1], 
    y - Re[2 x2 x6 - x7], -x6 Re[x1], x5/2 + Im[2 x2 x6 - x7], 
    x6 Im[x1]}, {-x6 Re[x1], 0, -x6 Im[x1], 0, -x6 Re[x1], y + x8, 
    x6 Im[x1], x4/2}, {0, -x6 Im[x1], 0, 
    x6 Re[x1], -(x5/2) - Im[2 x2 x6 - x7], -x6 Im[x1], 
    y - Re[2 x2 x6 - x7], -x6 Re[x1]}, {-x6 Im[x1], 0, x6 Re[x1], 
    0, -x6 Im[x1], -(x4/2), -x6 Re[x1], y + x8}};
eq1 = Det[matA];
eq2 == x1 - x3/(x5/2 - I (2 x6 x2 - x7));
eq3 = x2 - (I x6 x1^2)/(I x8 + x4/2);
```

where `x1` and `x2` are complex and `x3` to `x7` are all real. I want to solve for some *real* `y` the following equations: `eq1=0`, `eq2=0` and `eq3=0`. I have tried the following method

1. Randomly choosing the values of `x3` to `x7`
2. With these values solve `eq2=0` and `eq3=0` for `x1` and `x2`
3. Use `x1` and `x2` thus obtained in `eq1=0` and solve for `y`

However, I could not find any *real* value of `y` so far by this hit-n-trial method. Any help to find a *real* value of `y` would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Thanks to $\textbf{Bill}$, I corrected `X1` to `x1` in `eq2`.

Comment: Does this help? Replace `x1` with `rex1+I*imx1` and `x2` with `rex2+I*imx2` in `matA,eq2,eq3`  Then `NMinimize[Abs[eq1]+Abs[eq2]+Abs[eq3],{rex1,imx1,rex2,imx2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,y}]` That quickly finds values where your three equations are almost exactly equal to zero and gives you imaginary values for `x1,x2` and real values for `x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,y`

Comment: Thanks, @Bill, could you post it as an answer? Don't know why its not working on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

As requested

Replace `x1` with `(rex1+I*imx1)` and `x2` with `(rex2+I*imx2)` in `matA,eq2,eq3`

Then

```
NMinimize[Abs[eq1]+Abs[eq2]+Abs[eq3],{rex1,imx1,rex2,imx2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,y}]
```

That quickly finds values where your three equations are almost exactly equal to zero and gives you imaginary values for `x1,x2` and real values for `x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,y`

You also have one capitalized `X1` that should be `x1` in `eq2` and you could optionally simplify `matA` a tiny bit if you look at the `Re` and `Im` in that and make small changes to reflect `rex1,imx1,rex2,imx2` are all four real values, but this isn't required.

If you still can't get it then scrape-n-paste this into a newly opened MMA
and hope that I haven't made any mistakes copying this here.

```
In[1]:= matA = {{y+Re[2 (rex2+I*imx2) x6-x7], x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)], - 
 (x5/2)-Im[2 (rex2+I*imx2) x6-x7], -x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)], 0,
 x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)], 0, x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)]},
 {x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)], y-x8, -x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)], -(x4/2),
 x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)], 0, x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)], 0},
 {x5/2+Im[2 (rex2+I*imx2) x6-x7], x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)],
 y+Re[2 (rex2+I*imx2) x6-x7], x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)], 0,
 x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)], 0, -x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)]},
 {x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)], x4/2, x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)], y-x8,
 x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)], 0, -x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)], 0}, {0,
 -x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)], 0, -x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)],
 y-Re[2 (rex2+I*imx2) x6-x7], -x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)],
 x5/2+Im[2 (rex2+I*imx2) x6-x7], x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)]},
 {-x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)], 0, -x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)], 0,
 -x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)], y+x8, x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)], x4/2},
 {0, -x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)], 0, x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)],
 -(x5/2)-Im[2 (rex2+I*imx2) x6-x7], -x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)],
 y-Re[2 (rex2+I*imx2) x6-x7], -x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)]},
 {-x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)], 0, x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)], 0,
 -x6 Im[(rex1+I*imx1)], -(x4/2), -x6 Re[(rex1+I*imx1)], y+x8}};
eq1 = Det[matA];
eq2 = (rex1+I*imx1)-x3/(x5/2-I (2 x6 (rex2+I*imx2)-x7));
eq3 = (rex2+I*imx2)-(I x6 (rex1+I*imx1)^2)/(I x8+x4/2);
NMinimize[Abs[eq1]+Abs[eq2]+Abs[eq3], 
 {rex1,imx1,rex2,imx2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,y}]

Out[5]= {0.000190047,{rex1->-0.0328982,imx1->0.269316,
  rex2->-0.0209455,imx2->-0.0300461,x3->-0.142023,x4->0.301272,
  x5->0.140619,x6->0.113807,x7->0.514826,x8->0.172129,y->-0.0809267}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I could fix the issue already. My only worry is how close this is to my original question where I need a real $y$ from $eq1=0$ subjected to $eq2=0$ and $eq3=0$.

Comment: Understood. As I said, this was only a quick method to get close when your original post said you could not get anything. That does give a real y for eq1,eq2,eq3 close to zero. If I modify this `eq1=Simplify[Det[matA],Element[rex1|rex2|imx1|imx2|x6|x7,Reals]]` and follow that with `NMinimize[Abs[eq1]+Abs[eq2]+Abs[eq3],
{rex1,imx1,rex2,imx2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,y},WorkingPrecision->64]` then I get an error of 1.2*10^-6 which is the sum of the error for eq1,eq2,eq3. With more care and work I suspect that error could be reduced even more. You might get exact answer with very CAREFUL work,long time

Comment: `Abs` makes it harder for `NMinimize` `eq1` is real so replace `Abs[eq1]` with `eq1^2` and the error drops to 9.9*10^-7. Find any correct way to get rid of the other two `Abs` and `NMinimize` will be able to do a much better job and get an even smaller error. With that there might even be a chance that `Solve` or `Reduce` could find exact solutions with LOTS of memory and LOTS and LOTS of time to work on it.